# Bounding limit of sum of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I wish to find an upper bound for the limit superior of the following sequence in $n$:

$$\Big(3(n+1)\sum_{d \leq n/3}\binom{n}{d}\Big)^{1/n}.$$

In Theorem 3 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.09575.pdf), (where $\mu_3^S := \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}|F_3(n)|^{1/n}$, and $F_3(n)$ is the largest size of a type of set $F$ which we know is bounded by $3(n+1)\sum_{d \leq n/3}\binom{n}{d}$), the assertion is made that $\mu_3^S \leq \frac{3}{2^{2/3}}$, but I am failing to see how this value is obtained.

Edit: I now see how the value is obtained (thanks to a user in the comments). Stirling's approximation says that, for $0 \leq k/n \leq 1/2$,

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i} \leq 2^{H(k/n)n}.$$

where $H(\epsilon)$ is the binary entropy function. Then applying this bound and taking the limit of the original sequence as $n \rightarrow \infty$ to the power of $1/n$ gives the bound of $2^{H(1/3)}$, which is equal to $\frac{3}{2^{2/3}}$.

Comment: That seems like a pretty tight bound.  ${3\over2^{2/3}}\approx1.8898815748423097$ and calling the given expression $f(n)$ I get $f(1000)\approx1.899052795323168$ and $f(1100)\approx1.897898692628178$

Comment: Replace all the terms in the sum with the largest term, which is around $\binom{n}{n/3}$. Since $\limsup n^{1/n} = 1$, the  lim sup is bounded above by $\limsup \binom{n}{n/3}^{1/n}$. But now Stirling's formula does the job.

Answer (score 1):

*This is too long for a comment and more than likely too complex.*

In fact, we can compute exactly
$$3(n+1)\sum_{d=0}^{\frac n3} \binom{n}{d}=3 (n+1)\,  \left(2^{n}-\binom{n}{\frac{n+3}{3}} \, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{3-2
   n}{3};\frac{n+6}{3};-1\right)\right)$$ Fos simplicity, let $n=3\times 10^k$ and compute the value of the given expression
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 2.104236001 \\
 2 & 1.918190978 \\
 3 & 1.893429244 \\
 4 & 1.890308683 \\
 5 & 1.889931535 \\
 6 & 1.889887296 \\
 7 & 1.889882219
\end{array}
\right)$$ while $\frac{3}{2^{2/3}}=1.889881575$.